# SoapUI Webservice Testing: Can we test an API connection through SoapUI without running the API?

Tags: api, web-services, soapui, health-monitoring, apimonitor

I come across a requirement to test if the webservice is responding(API Monitoring). Although we can't run the API as it is a Production API and it will issue orders.

I am currently using SoapUI and wondering if there's a way we could do it there?

Thanks.

Comment: You can do an http request to the wsdl.

Comment: You have to add `?WSDL` at the end of the link. For example : `http://localhost:8041/services/getListOfDocuments?WSDL`

Answer (score 1):

Do the following in a Groovy Script step:

```
def req = new URL("http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl").openConnection()
def resp = req.getResponseCode()


if (resp.equals(200)) {
    log.info('pass')
    def respContent = req.getInputStream().getText()
}
else {
    log.info('fail')
}
```